# promQL opetrate two metric with same labels, but different label-val combiantions,

Tags: prometheus, promql, opentsdb, victoriametrics

I have to metric one metric is total count, another is error count, they have same labels, but different label-val combination, total count metric's label-vals combinations mush constains error count metric's label-val combination,such as:

total count metric:

```
method_totalCall{host="h1", dst="a1", src="a2"}@t1 = 24
method_totalCall{host="h1", dst="b1", src="b2"}@t1 = 30
method_totalCall{host="h1", dst="c1", src="c2"}@t1 = 3
method_totalCall{host="h1", dst="d1", src="d2"}@t1 = 6
method_totalCall{host="h1", dst="e1", src="e2"}@t1 = 21
```

this metric means method call count in $host from $src to $dest

error count metric:

```
method_totalCall_ERROR{host="h1", dst="c1", src="c2"}@t1 = 1
method_totalCall_ERROR{host="h1", dst="d1", src="d2"}@t1 = 2
method_totalCall_ERROR{host="h1", dst="e1", src="e2"}@t1 = 3
```

this metric means method call error count in `$host` from `$src` to `$dest`

i want to get a metric which means method call success count in `$host` from `$src` to `$dest`
so i write a promQL:

```
method_totalCall{host='h1'} - method_totalCall_ERROR{host='h1'}
```

but
if i use promQL :

```
method_totalCall{host='h1'} - method_totalCall_ERROR{host='h1'}
```

I will get a new temporary metric :

```
methed_succ_count{host="h1", dst="c1", src="c2"}@t1 = 2 
methed_succ_count{host="h1", dst="d1", src="d2"}@t1 = 4
methed_succ_count{host="h1", dst="e1", src="e2"}@t1 = 18


(come from:method_totalCall{host="h1", dst="c1", src="c2"}@t1 - method_totalCall_ERROR{host="h1", dst="c1", src="c2"}@t1)
(come from:method_totalCall{host="h1", dst="d1", src="d2"}@t1 - method_totalCall_ERROR{host="h1", dst="d1", src="d2"}@t1)
(come from:method_totalCall{host="h1", dst="e1", src="e2"}@t1 - method_totalCall_ERROR{host="h1", dst="e1", src="e2"}@t1)
```

but for label

```
{host="h1", dst="a1", src="a2"}
{host="h1", dst="b1", src="b2"}
```

value missed in new metric. which means i doesn't get the sucess count in host h1 from  from specific `$src(a1, b1)` to specific `$dest(a2,b2)`.how should I modify promQL? i want get val like this:

```
methed_succ_count{host="h1", dst="a1", src="a2"}@t1 = 24
methed_succ_count{host="h1", dst="b1", src="b2"}@t1 = 30
methed_succ_count{host="h1", dst="c1", src="c2"}@t1 = 2 
methed_succ_count{host="h1", dst="d1", src="d2"}@t1 = 4
methed_succ_count{host="h1", dst="e1", src="e2"}@t1 = 18
```

which means when no error occur on host h1 from some specific `$src(a1, b1)` to specific `$dst (a2,b2)`， error count is zero from `(a1,b1)` to `(a2, b2)`, success count from `(a1, b1)` to `(a2, b2)` is total count.

the tsdb i used is victoriametrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you are trying to do, is to create a left join.
PromQL doesn't have built-in operator for this, but it can be emulated with `or`.

In your particular case, use

```
method_totalCall{host='h1'} - method_totalCall_ERROR{host='h1'}
 or method_totalCall{host='h1'}
```

For more details on the matter check [this post](https://www.robustperception.io/left-joins-in-promql/) by Brian Brasil.

---

A sidenote, regarding metric naming: you metric names don't conform to [the best practices](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/#metric-names).

Additionally, consider (if possible) changing your instrumentation, so that you actually expose metric with the single name, but additional label `result` that would contain values `Success` or `Failure`. This way you have values split by results, and if you need aggregation for total call, you can use `sum without (result) (method_calls_total)`.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer a lot, i will try your instruction later, in the future metric name ,i will follow the best practice. Then, I want to ask an extra question, if i use promQL: metricA  or metricB, metricA have some same label-label_val combination with metricB, whose metric val will be reserved on these same label-label_val combinations?

Comment: thanks, it works A - B  or B. i agree you opinion, i should use label(result) to seperate success and error in one metric. but i think my scenario is necessary, for example ,if i want to calculate error rate, i should use methedcallcount(result=error,host=h1)/methedcallcount{host=h1}, i want get 0% when no error occur on some  label-label_val combination, but this value missed.
please give me some suggestion,if i want to get deep understanding about promQL grammar's details which can help me to write complex and right promQL to deal with my kinds of scenario. what shoul i do
thank you again.

Comment: @i_have_a_question, if both metrics have exactly the same labels, `or` will return first one. I recommend  going through prometheus' documentation on querying: it's rather consize but very helpful. Additionally, look through linked blog by Brian Brasil: he is one of creators of Prometheus and posted very useful ideas there.

Comment: thanks, i got it. i will read the prometheus's doc about query and the post from  Brian Brasil carefully. I think the query documention in prometheus `https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/`does't have enough details, such as "which val will be return when i use operator `or` operate two metric which have some exactly same labels". i must do some experiment or ask other experts like you to get answer.

Comment: @i_have_a_question, description of `or` behaviour is not in the api section, but in the [operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators).

Comment: thanks, i found the important information ```The metric name and values are carried over from the left-hand side vector.``` in originally english version doc was dropped in chinese doc....